# Simple SQL JOIN Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join

I have a simple `JOIN` that I'm having issues with the `SQL` below.  This statement returns 1 record, but if I comment out line #5 it doesn't return any. Any ideas?

```
SELECT A.district__c, b.annual_conference__c
FROM   Contact_UpdateDistricts A
JOIN   Contact B on a.id = b.id
WHERE  A.error NOT LIKE '%success%'
and a.id = '003Z000000C80tUIAR'
and A.district__c <> b.annual_conference__c
```

Comment: Consider re-writing your query into ansi sql instead of that.

Comment: Please don't link your code. Add your code here. And also show your data structure.

Comment: So you uncomment line 5 and it returns rows? This means that a.id is not equal to the value you specified.

Comment: yes If I include line 5 I get 1 record as expected returned. If I remove it I do not get any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up casting the last clause for the resolution:

```
SELECT A.district__c, b.annual_conference__c 
FROM Contact_UpdateDistricts A 
JOIN Contact B on a.id = b.id 
WHERE A.error NOT LIKE '%success%' 
and CAST(A.district__c AS VARCHAR(18)) <> CAST(b.annual_conference__c AS VARCHAR(18))
```